# Account Territory Sharing Rule remediation in Enterprise Territory Management

Tags: sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing, territory-management

Account Territory Sharing rule is no longer available to ETM, and as per salesforce the remediation should be like below:

[Original Territory Management (TM1) to Enterprise Territory Management (ETM/TM2) Migration FAQ](https://quip.com/1KTFAbTVe6Ke)

Account Territory Sharing Rules available under TM1 will not be available under ETM. This function essentially shares all the accounts that are assigned to a particular territory to another target (user, group, role etc). ***We suggest that you define additional territories that would contain the original sharing target members, and utilize the same territory assignment rules from the source territories on the new territories.***

How to create sharing rule same as below

```
Accounts in Territory and Subordinate of 'Medical' to be shared with Territory and Subordinate of 'Medical' .
```

We do not have any assignment rule, if one Account belongs one of the territories in 'Medical' Territory Hierarchy, should be available to all the 'Medical' Territory Hierarchy.
Please suggest.
If the only solution is apex sharing then please let me know.